# Is there a Rails macro to dynamically add many similar methods to a Model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dynamic, metaprogramming

I feel like I read somewhere about an ActiveRecord macro that dynamically generated many similar instance methods on a Model, but now (despite looking through online docs and RoR books) I can't find it.

I have solved the problem using plain old Ruby, but if there's a better (more Rails-y) way to do it, I'd like to know about it.

So, I have `Character`, `Gear` and `Modifiers` models (yes, this an app for an RPG). The Character will have Gear that adds modifiers to his stats.  So I want a method for each stat that queries his gear (and his gear's modifiers) and sums the modifiers for the relevant stats.  (See the method in the code below).

So my Character model looks like this:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gears
  has_many :modifiers, :as => :modifiable, :through => :gears

  stats = ["hp", "bab", "ac"]  # etc...


  stats.each do |method_name|
    define_method method_name do 
      self.modifiers.where(:kind => method_name).sum(:amount)  
    end    
  end

end
```

So, this way I can do

```
>  jim = Character.create(:name => "Jim")
```

and then give Jim some gear that modifies his "hp", "bab" or "ac" and then I can just do this:

```
>  jim.hp
```

or

```
>  jim.ac
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

This is not a more (Rails-y) way but it is an alternative to your code. With method missing.

Where is what [rubylearning.com](http://rubylearning.com) has to say about it.

When you send a message to an object, the object executes the first method it finds on its method lookup path with the same name as the message. If it fails to find any such method, it raises a NoMethodError exception - unless you have provided the object with a method called method_missing...

```
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)  
  self.modifiers.where(:kind => method_name).sum(:amount)    
end
```

The Pros about this approach is that you don't need to be maintaining your stats array and looping thru them to define a method for each stat. The cons is that it can be dangerous if every time that there is a missing_method for a User it goes and execute this code.

Comment: Starting to wonder if I may have been mistaken about the alternative.  I was aware of good old method_missing, but your explanation of the pros and cons of it in my situation is very helpful.  The relief at not needing to maintain the array of skills is worth a lot.

Comment: Wondering if I should "accept" this answer as correct?  It might be the most helpful answer to someone asking my question, even though it doesn't--strictly speaking--answer it.  Thougts @rogeliog?

Comment: Thats up to you, if you consider it as a correct answer then accept it. But don't feel forced to do it. If you still haven't solved your problem and need a better answer you shouldn't accept it. If you have solved your problem you can accept it and even edit my answer. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of `ActiveRecord::Base.store`, which showed up in Rails 3.2. With it, you can do something like this:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :stats, accessors: [:hp, :bab, :ac]
end
 
jim = Character.create(:name => "Jim")
jim.hp = 100
```

Note: The `stats` column should be defined as a `text` column to make sure you have enough room for your values.

[Read more in the Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)

Comment: I don't think store is what I'm looking for, I'll explain why in my upcoming question edti.

Comment: What my code above does is generates a method for each "stat" that sums all of the modifiers that exist for that stat.